# Can't add data from json in ArrayList

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to display data from JSON in listView, but whenever I'll try to add some value from json, my list shows me nothing.

Activity

```
public static final String LOG = hourlyWeather.class.getSimpleName();
    double test;
    RequestQueue mQuene;
    ArrayList<Weather> list;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_hourly_weather);
        mQuene =  Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

        list = new ArrayList<Weather>();
        test();

        hourlyWeatherAdapter adapter = new hourlyWeatherAdapter(this, list);

        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.weatherListView);

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
    public void test() {
        String url = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=50.7578594&lon=16.2127653&units=metric&appid=ID";
        JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
                response -> {
                    try {
                        JSONObject object = response.getJSONObject("main");
                        for (int i = 0; i<object.length(); i++){
                            test = object.getDouble("temp");
                        }
                        Log.i(LOG,String.valueOf(test));
                        list.add(new Weather(test));

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }, Throwable::printStackTrace);
        mQuene.add(request);
    }
}
```

Adapter

```
public class hourlyWeatherAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Weather> {

public hourlyWeatherAdapter(@NonNull Context context, ArrayList<Weather> list) {
    super(context, 0, list);
}
@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

    View view = convertView;
    if (view == null) {
        view = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.weather_list_item, parent, false);
    }
    Weather model = getItem(position);

    TextView temperature = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.hourly_time);
    temperature.append(String.valueOf(model.getTemp()));

    return view;
 } 
}

public class Weather {

private double temp;

public Weather(double temp) {
    this.temp = temp;
}

public double getTemp() {
    return temp;
 }
}
```

When I'll using the Log.i, I can clearly see value from json in my logcat. Where can be issue? I've tried to add some dummy data, and it works out just fine.

Comment: You already use `Log` to print and check if your data is really received?

Comment: Yes, here's the value:   I/hourlyWeather: 16.77

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must declare `hourlyWeatherAdapter adapter = new hourlyWeatherAdapter(this, list);` outside your `onCreate()` method, and after change your array, you must call `notifyDataSetChanged();`. Also, you must initialize your list and adapter before call `test()`.

```
public static final String LOG = hourlyWeather.class.getSimpleName();
    double test;
    RequestQueue mQuene;
    ArrayList<Weather> list;
    hourlyWeatherAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_hourly_weather);
        mQuene =  Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

        list = new ArrayList<Weather>();
        adapter = new hourlyWeatherAdapter(this, list);

        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.weatherListView);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        test();
    }

    public void test() {
        String url = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=50.7578594&lon=16.2127653&units=metric&appid=ID";
        JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
            response -> {
                try {
                    JSONObject object = response.getJSONObject("main");
                    for (int i = 0; i<object.length(); i++){
                        test = object.getDouble("temp");
                    }
                    Log.i(LOG,String.valueOf(test));
                    list.add(new Weather(test));

                    // Update list
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }, Throwable::printStackTrace);
       mQuene.add(request);
    }
}
```